# How can I request a specific connection from com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource?

Tags: java, datasource, connection-pooling

Problem:

- Program uses `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` to connect to Sybase server
- Program executes 2 methods, `runSQL1()` and `runSQL2()`, in sequence
- `runSQL1()` executes SQL which creates a #temptable

  ```
  SELECT * INTO #myTemp FROM TABLE1 WHERE X=2
  ```
- `runSQL2()` executes SQL which reads from this #temptable

  ```
  SELECT * FROM #myTemp WHERE Y=3
  ```
- ***PROBLEM***: `runSQL2()` gets handed a different DB connection from the pool than the one handed to `runSQL1()`.

  However, Sybase #temptables are connection-specific, therefore **`runSQL2()` fails when it can't find the table**.

The most obvious solution I can think of (aside from degenerate one of making pool size 1, at which point we don't even need a pool), is to somehow remember which specific connection from the pool was used by `runSQL1()`, and have `runSQL2()` request **the same connection**.

## Is there a way to do this in `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`?

If possible, I'd like an answer which is concurrency-safe (in other words, if connection used in runSQL1() is being used by another thread, runSQL2()'s call to get connection will wait until that connection is released by another thread).

However, if that's impossible, I'm OK with the answer which assumes that DB connections (the ones I care about) are all happening in one single thread, and therefore any connection requested by runSQL2() will be 100% available if it was available to runSQL1().

I'm also welcoming of any solutions that address the problem some other way, as long as they don't involve "stop using #temptables" as part of the solution.

Comment: Why can't you request the connection before running part1 and then pass that as a parameter to both calls?

Comment: @ivan did that.  But I don't like this solution so I'd like to know how to get specific connection instead

Comment: I also think the solution proposed by @Ivan is the proper solution. In order to get it in any other way, you need to hold at least an identifier to the connection when you first receive it. After doing it you need to use reflection  on the pool managers and find the matching connection. Instead of doing that just holding a reference to the specific connection is more clean. If you really need to do this by querying with an identifier, you can write your own wrapper connection manager and use that.

Comment: What are you doing with your `ComboPooledDataSource`? It should stay open for the time of database usage. Use it to get your connection object from it. If the #temptable relies on a specific connection then you can only re-use the same connection with which you've executed `runSQL1()`. Also, have you tried to create _shareable temporary table_?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most obvious way to do that is just to request connection from the pool and then run `runSQL1()` and `runSQL2()` with that connection. Usage pattern being suggested in the question goes against general design principles of connection pool managers, as it will effectively promote them to some kind of transaction manager.

There are Java frameworks that might aid in the above. For example in Spring `@Transaction` or `TransactionTemplate` can be used to demarcate transaction boundaries and it will guarantee that single connection is used by single thread (or more precisely, according to transaction propagation annotations). Spring can use many transaction managers, but probably simplest would be to use [DataSourceTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html) and it can also be configured to use `c3p0` as `DataSource`.